# IIS detected a deadlock, but unable to substantiate that with memory dump

Tags: asp.net, iis, deadlock, windbg

I have a customer that occasional reports an IIS deadlock. It is a rather large managed ASP.Net application spanning multiple servers, but in this case is occurring on a simple web server that either returns static files (HTTP, Javascript) or acts as a proxy and calls a webservice on an application tier. Note that this is a .Net 3.5 application and the application pool uses the classic pipeline.

I have a dump of this and have been analyzing it, but as far as I can tell, there are no resources being blocked in such a way for a deadlock to occur.

The faulting thread is #4 and belongs to IIS. The stack indicates that it checks for health problems, finds one (deadlock?), and fails the worker process.

```
0:004> kv
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00000000`01b1e6c0 000007fe`f8c96d82 : 00000000`01b1e810 00000000`00000000 00000000`01b1e848 00000000`01b1e848 : KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x39
01 00000000`01b1e790 000007fe`f80779cc : 00000000`05da4c58 00000000`00000082 00000000`05da4c58 00000000`00000082 : w3wphost!W3WP_HOST::FailWorkerProcess+0x2e
02 00000000`01b1e7e0 000007fe`f80728cb : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`000c000a : isapi!RegisterModule+0xcce4
03 00000000`01b1e830 000007fe`f806dd84 : 00000000`01b1ed40 00000000`00000020 00000000`00000004 000007fe`00000020 : isapi!RegisterModule+0x7be3
04 00000000`01b1ecf0 000007fe`f7f07459 : 00000000`05da4c58 00000000`05da4c58 00000000`05da4c58 000007fe`f806e06f : isapi!RegisterModule+0x309c
05 00000000`01b1edd0 000007fe`f7f07617 : 01cefba1`36242e6e 000007fe`f80419d6 00000000`00000000 00000000`05da4c58 : webengine!ReportHealthProblem+0xc9
06 00000000`01b1ef30 000007fe`f7f08d6b : 01cefba1`34feed30 01cefba1`36242e6e 00000000`05da4c58 00000000`00000000 : webengine!CheckAndReportHealthProblems+0xb7
07 00000000`01b1ef60 000007fe`f806c540 : 00000000`0126a088 00000000`05da4c58 00000000`01b1f330 000007fe`f8063588 : webengine!AspNetHttpExtensionProc+0x1db
...
```

The first thing that I checked was for a deadlock with !dlk; none are detected.

```
0:004> !dlk
Examining SyncBlocks...
Scanning for ReaderWriterLock instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLock locks...
Scanning for ReaderWriterLockSlim instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLockSlim locks...
Examining CriticalSections...
No deadlocks detected.
```

Reportedly !dlk does not find some deadlocks, so I next check !threads to see if any are holding locks. Quite a few are.
These are threads are calling webservices on another server.

```
0:004> !threads
ThreadCount: 63
UnstartedThread: 0
BackgroundThread: 57
PendingThread: 0
DeadThread: 6
Hosted Runtime: no
                                              PreEmptive                                                Lock
       ID OSID        ThreadOBJ     State   GC     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count APT Exception
   7    1  96c 00000000021394a0      8220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 Ukn
  16    2  9a4 0000000002142250      b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 MTA (Finalizer)
  17    4  a64 00000000021913c0    80a220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
  18    5  a70 00000000021930f0      1220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 Ukn
  20    e  b6c 00000000022700e0   880b220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
   6    b  968 0000000005aaf0b0       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 Ukn
   4   41  960 0000000005ab0220       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 Ukn
   5   4f  964 0000000005a647c0       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 Ukn
  30   ac  700 0000000005aafc50       220 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 Ukn
XXXX   a7    0 0000000005ab1960   1801820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   aa    0 0000000005dcf540   1801820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   be    0 0000000005dce3d0   1801820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   ae    0 0000000005dcd830   1801820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   38    0 0000000005ab0dc0      9820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 MTA
XXXX   39    0 0000000005ab2500      9820 Enabled  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 00000000012e41d0     0 MTA
  31   37 133c 0000000005ab07f0   180b220 Enabled  00000001c0668760:00000001c0668d50 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  32   34  ce8 0000000005d93550   180b220 Enabled  00000001806563a8:0000000180657ad0 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  33   c4  be4 0000000005d90ca0   180b220 Enabled  00000001c065e7b0:00000001c065ed50 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  34  101  5a0 0000000005d923e0   180b220 Enabled  000000014072bfa0:000000014072daa0 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  36   c5  6c0 0000000005d906d0   180b220 Enabled  000000010004d360:000000010004e150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  37   35  76c 0000000005d940f0   180b220 Enabled  000000010005a950:000000010005c150 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  38   36  cdc 0000000005d92f80   180b220 Enabled  0000000100069c20:000000010006a150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  39   33  b90 0000000005d91e10   180b220 Enabled  000000014072f460:000000014072faa0 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  40   32 12b8 0000000005d929b0   180b220 Enabled  0000000100083520:0000000100084150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  41   31 11d8 0000000005d95e00   180b220 Enabled  0000000100091cb0:0000000100092150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  42   30  d78 0000000005d946c0   180b220 Enabled  00000001000a3af8:00000001000a4150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  43   2f  bd8 0000000005d95830   180b220 Enabled  00000001000b1200:00000001000b2150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  44   2e  598 0000000005d91840   180b220 Enabled  00000001000bf808:00000001000c0150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  45   2d  ba0 0000000005d93b20   180b220 Enabled  00000001000cd698:00000001000ce150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  46   2c 136c 0000000005d94c90   180b220 Enabled  00000001000df068:00000001000e0150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  47   ca  8f0 0000000005d90100   180b220 Enabled  00000001000ed618:00000001000ee150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  48  102  d14 0000000005d95260   180b220 Enabled  00000001000fc7d0:00000001000fe150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  49   cb 12c0 0000000005d91270   180b220 Enabled  000000010010cf88:000000010010e150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  50   c7  e98 0000000005d969a0   180b220 Enabled  000000010011c618:000000010011e150 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  51   e2  d74 0000000005d96f70   180b220 Enabled  000000010012b758:000000010012c150 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  52   c2 1278 0000000005d97540   180b220 Enabled  00000001001395e0:000000010013a150 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  53   c8  8e0 0000000005d963d0   180b220 Enabled  0000000100148898:000000010014a150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  54   c6  24c 0000000005aaf680   180b220 Enabled  00000001001595d8:000000010015a150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  55   c9  708 0000000005ab1f30   180b220 Enabled  0000000180658120:0000000180659ad0 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  56   c3 110c 0000000005ab1390   180b220 Enabled  0000000100176ce8:0000000100178150 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  57   cd  8dc 0000000005dc8100   180b220 Enabled  000000010018c0f8:000000010018c150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  58   d1  588 0000000005dca9b0   180b220 Enabled  000000010019a620:000000010019c150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  59   d0  31c 0000000005dc8ca0   180b220 Enabled  00000001001ab9a0:00000001001ac150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  60   1a  cb4 0000000005dca3e0   180b220 Enabled  00000001001ba7f8:00000001001bc150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  61   1b 13cc 0000000005dc9840   180b220 Enabled  00000001001ca798:00000001001cc150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  62   1c 12f4 0000000005dccc90   180b220 Enabled  00000001001da7d0:00000001001dc150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  63   1d 11c8 0000000005dc86d0   180b220 Enabled  00000001001eab48:00000001001ec150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  64   1e 1304 0000000005dcde00   180b220 Enabled  00000001001fa960:00000001001fc150 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  65   1f 1258 0000000005dcbb20   180b220 Enabled  000000010020ab18:000000010020c150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  66   20  854 0000000005dc9270   180b220 Enabled  00000001407307c8:0000000140731aa0 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  67   21 13bc 0000000005dcaf80   180b220 Enabled  000000010022bd30:000000010022c150 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  68   22  c4c 0000000005dc9e10   180b220 Enabled  00000001002409f0:0000000100242150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  69   23 10dc 0000000005dcc6c0   180b220 Enabled  0000000100251c70:0000000100252150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  70   24  264 0000000005dcc0f0   180b220 Enabled  0000000100261288:0000000100262150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  71   25  3c8 0000000005dcb550   180b220 Enabled  0000000100271688:0000000100272150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  72   26  b88 0000000005dcd260   180b220 Enabled  0000000100287420:0000000100288150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  74   27 1318 0000000005dce9a0   180b220 Enabled  00000001002975c8:0000000100298150 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  75   28  bdc 0000000005dcef70   180b220 Enabled  00000001002a6d48:00000001002a8150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  76   29  100 0000000005a65930   180b220 Enabled  00000001002b7698:00000001002b8150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  77   2a  e5c 0000000005a67070   180b220 Enabled  00000001002c70f8:00000001002c8150 0000000002248da0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  78   2b  434 0000000005a67c10   180b220 Enabled  00000001002d6b78:00000001002d8150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  79   cc  e4c 0000000005a65360   180b220 Enabled  00000001002e65f8:00000001002e8150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  80   3a  dd0 0000000005a64d90   180b220 Enabled  00000001002f66c0:00000001002f8150 0000000002193ba0     1 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
```

Next I check if any of the threads are hung. All are well under a minute, and those above 10 seconds belong to the ASP.Net infrastructure without any of our code running on them.

```
0:004> !runaway
User Mode Time
  Thread       Time
   4:960       0 days 0:00:39.843
   5:964       0 days 0:00:33.281
   6:968       0 days 0:00:25.906
   7:96c       0 days 0:00:24.000
  31:133c      0 days 0:00:09.437
  14:99c       0 days 0:00:06.953
  32:ce8       0 days 0:00:06.921
  15:9a0       0 days 0:00:06.890
  13:998       0 days 0:00:06.750
  30:700       0 days 0:00:06.062
  33:be4       0 days 0:00:04.937
  12:994       0 days 0:00:04.640
  26:9f8       0 days 0:00:02.859
  34:5a0       0 days 0:00:01.203
  16:9a4       0 days 0:00:00.765
   0:934       0 days 0:00:00.062
  17:a64       0 days 0:00:00.031
  65:1258      0 days 0:00:00.015
  52:1278      0 days 0:00:00.015
  21:1338      0 days 0:00:00.015
  80:dd0       0 days 0:00:00.000
  79:e4c       0 days 0:00:00.000
  78:434       0 days 0:00:00.000
  77:e5c       0 days 0:00:00.000
  76:100       0 days 0:00:00.000
  75:bdc       0 days 0:00:00.000
  74:1318      0 days 0:00:00.000
  73:77c       0 days 0:00:00.000
  72:b88       0 days 0:00:00.000
  71:3c8       0 days 0:00:00.000
  70:264       0 days 0:00:00.000
  69:10dc      0 days 0:00:00.000
  68:c4c       0 days 0:00:00.000
  67:13bc      0 days 0:00:00.000
  66:854       0 days 0:00:00.000
  64:1304      0 days 0:00:00.000
  63:11c8      0 days 0:00:00.000
  62:12f4      0 days 0:00:00.000
  61:13cc      0 days 0:00:00.000
  60:cb4       0 days 0:00:00.000
  59:31c       0 days 0:00:00.000
  58:588       0 days 0:00:00.000
  57:8dc       0 days 0:00:00.000
  56:110c      0 days 0:00:00.000
  55:708       0 days 0:00:00.000
  54:24c       0 days 0:00:00.000
  53:8e0       0 days 0:00:00.000
  51:d74       0 days 0:00:00.000
  50:e98       0 days 0:00:00.000
  49:12c0      0 days 0:00:00.000
  48:d14       0 days 0:00:00.000
  47:8f0       0 days 0:00:00.000
  46:136c      0 days 0:00:00.000
  45:ba0       0 days 0:00:00.000
  44:598       0 days 0:00:00.000
  43:bd8       0 days 0:00:00.000
  42:d78       0 days 0:00:00.000
  41:11d8      0 days 0:00:00.000
  40:12b8      0 days 0:00:00.000
  39:b90       0 days 0:00:00.000
  38:cdc       0 days 0:00:00.000
  37:76c       0 days 0:00:00.000
  36:6c0       0 days 0:00:00.000
  35:11b4      0 days 0:00:00.000
  29:11b8      0 days 0:00:00.000
  28:438       0 days 0:00:00.000
  27:12d8      0 days 0:00:00.000
  25:e44       0 days 0:00:00.000
  24:670       0 days 0:00:00.000
  23:1284      0 days 0:00:00.000
  22:139c      0 days 0:00:00.000
  20:b6c       0 days 0:00:00.000
  19:adc       0 days 0:00:00.000
  18:a70       0 days 0:00:00.000
  11:990       0 days 0:00:00.000
  10:988       0 days 0:00:00.000
   9:984       0 days 0:00:00.000
   8:970       0 days 0:00:00.000
   3:954       0 days 0:00:00.000
   2:940       0 days 0:00:00.000
   1:938       0 days 0:00:00.000
```

Still curious about the locks being held on threads, I check !mlocks. It indicates that these are all thinlocks belonging to System.Web.HttpApplication instances being created by ASP.Net. There is no recursion either, so this too looks fine.

I next check !threadpool. I have not used this very much so am not sure that I am interpreting the output correctly, but it would appear that the application has not yet reached the limit (400) and there are no waiting requests, so this would appear to be OK.

```
0:004> !threadpool
CPU utilization 0%
Worker Thread: Total: 48 Running: 48 Idle: 0 MaxLimit: 400 MinLimit: 4
Work Request in Queue: 0
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 34
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread:Total: 1 Free: 1 MaxFree: 8 CurrentLimit: 0 MaxLimit: 400 MinLimit: 4
```

I have been analyzing this off and on for a few days now and am at a loss to understand this issue and would appreciate suggestions on how to identify this "health problem" that IIS has detected.

***Update***
The thread stacks were too large to include here, so I have uploaded them to [here](http://pastebin.com/JCsVtbaE). The company types have been renamed to Foo.Bar for privacy reasons. The method name 0 is due to actual obfuscation.

***Update 2***
Thanks to the comments, I found [KB 821268](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268), which seems relevant. I must not be interpreting the output of !threadpool correctly. It indicates Total: 48, Running: 48 (and Idle: 0) which may mean that it is exhausted, but then I do not know how what this means with regard to MaxLimit: 400. Perhaps someone can set me straight on this.

Comment: Can you post all the stacks? (~*kc)

Comment: @RemusRusanu It exceeds the maximum message length. Can you recommend any public sites to post this?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4643

Comment: @RemusRusanu Thank you. I updated the question with a link to the full stacks.

Comment: You have a large number of requests in `Foo.Bar.Proxy.ProcessRequest` waiting for a HTTP response. It seems to me you exhausted all ASP handlers in waiting for a HTTP response from somewhere. This will be reported as a deadlock I think. Did you consider an [async ASP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433(v=vs.100).aspx) instead? Going async will free your IIS/ASP threads.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I noticed that as well. However, !runaway does not indicate poor performance, though. How can I verify if all of the ASP handlers are exhausted? Is that separate from the output in !threadpool, which seems to indicate that a max has not been reached yet? This is now a legacy product that was deployed at a customer site several years ago. Other customers have it as well and have not reported similar issues. So before changing it to async, I'd really like to verify that the handlers are exhausted as you mention.

Comment: Well, the limit is 400 and 48 'in use' is not that much. You also have 6 ['dead'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yunjin/archive/2005/08/29/457150.aspx) threads (~22, ~24-~29). I'm afraid I won't be able to RCA just from the info here and me going further would be much speculation... Perhaps going over [.NET Debugging Demos](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx) will give out some clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research and analysis, I was able to identify the cause of the problem. I was putting too much thought into the output of !threadpool. While the data was useful, all that it told me was that I had not exhausted either the worker or completion threads.

Rather, the real problem was in the number of active network connections. This value is set in the .config files. For .Net 2+ environments, it is typically auto-configured to 12 * #CPUs. For this dump, the number of CPUs is 4, resulting in a maximum of 48 open connections. This matches the number of threads reading data via HttpWebRequest as seen the stacks.

The initial clue for this came from [KB 821268](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268), though it lacked details on how to diagnose this. That verification was found in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2012/08/01/recycling-a-worker-process-due-to-deadlock.aspx) blog post. In short, I dumped all of the System.Net.ServicePoint objects on the heap. In each one is a m_CurrentConnections and m_ConnectionLimit. Summing all of the m_CurrentConnections gave me the total of open network connections, which for this dump was 48. Also, the m_ConnectionLimit verified that the maximum value was 48. The numbers matched. The maximum number of connections had been reached causing IIS to kill the process. This is not a "deadlock" per-say, but unfortunately IIS is not very specific about the problem or causes when leaving messages in the event logs.